# Can I get GCC to create truly position independent ARM32 code?

Tags: gcc, arm, bare-metal

What I'm after is ARM32 code that I can load and enter at a random memory location, and it will still work.

Function calls, access to constants, etc. should be PC-relative, the stack can be anywhere, I don't need global or static variables, but having them PC-relative would be a nice option.

There would be no "loader" program that relocates stuff, just take the binary and run it, wherever it is.

Simple function calls, for example, work OK, but a switch statement is sometimes implemented by an absolute jump table. It should be possible to make the jumps relative instead. (Possibly even more efficient, because it wouldn't involve the data cache, just the code cache.)

```
 6c8:   e3530012        cmp     r3, #18
 6cc:   979ff103        ldrls   pc, [pc, r3, lsl #2]
 6d0:   ea000015        b       72c
 6d4:   00000720        andeq   r0, r0, r0, lsr #14
 6d8:   00000778        andeq   r0, r0, r8, ror r7
 6dc:   0000072c        andeq   r0, r0, ip, lsr #14
```

Could just as easily be:

```
 6c8:   e3530012        cmp     r3, #18
 6cc:   979ff103        addls   pc, pc, r3, lsl #2
 6d0:   ea000015        b       72c
 6d4:   ea000011        b       720
 6d8:   ea000xxx        b       778
 6dc:   ea000012        b       72c
```

The latter code's `addls` is almost certainly incorrect, possibly the encodings of the jumps as well; for example only.

Answer (score 1):

-fpic Solves the particular problem with the switch statement.

```
 2c8:   e3530012        cmp     r3, #18
 2cc:   908ff103        addls   pc, pc, r3, lsl #2
 2d0:   ea00010d        b       70c <c_swi_handler+0x520>
 2d4:   ea000011        b       320 <c_swi_handler+0x134>
 2d8:   ea000010        b       320 <c_swi_handler+0x134>
 2dc:   ea00010a        b       70c <c_swi_handler+0x520>
```

Due to limitations of the linker (I think) access to the address of global constants and such is implemented not with a simple `ADR rX, label` (which translates to a addition or subtraction from PC), but a two-stage approach that loads a constant stored in the `.text` segment and then adds it to the PC. My linker script had discarded any segment starting `.data` (to warn me if I was using writable static or global variables), but a new segment `.data.rel.ro.local` is needed to satisfy the linker.